# Create spheres of random sizes inside a cylinder and randomly connect them

Tags: algorithm, geometry, connected-components

I know this is going to be very confusing question, you can ask me and I will try to give more details:

I want to create a network of randomly connected spheres with random sizes within some range. The spheres are inside an arbitrarily positioned cylinder.
Each sphere can be connected to a number of other spheres, let's say 5.
In the end, I should have randomly located spheres inside the cylinder, which have radii within some range `[r_min,r_max]`, and connected through lines (links) which have lengths within range `[L_min,L_max]`.

The way I approach this so far is that I have divided this task into two steps:
1) First, I want to create random points in 3D space inside the given cylinder.
2) Then I want to connect them. But I'm going to connect only those pairs that have the distance between them that satisfy 2 criteria:

- >= 2*minimum radius of the sphere+minimum length of link
- <= 2*maximum radius of the sphere+maximum length of link

And then I want to randomly divide that distance between centers to radii of 2 spheres and the length of the link.

So far, I've figured out how to create random points within cylinder

[image: MATLAB 3D plot]

My concern is first of all, how do I make sure that I have some continuous cluster of connected points from one end of cylinder to the other end (like not leaving any gap of unconnected points in the middle)? Secondly, how to write the code in the most efficient way? Thirdly, I would actually want to have more control on parameters, briefly speaking, I would want to randomly pick spheres from some collection of already created spheres and place them inside the cylinder and connect them? Is it possible to write the code that way?

P.S. programming language doesn't matter, I can write it in any, the main thing I want to figure out is the algorithm itself.

Comment: You can check that connected components of your cluster is one to assert that there is a path between each sphere. If they are not, you could either connect the unconnected ones, or re-run the sim until you get a single component.

Comment: "how to write the code in the most efficient way" is too broad - the best answer, is maybe: 'with a lot of efforts and precision'?

Comment: "Is it possible to write the code in a way that gives more control over the parameters?" --> yes.

Comment: Your connectivity problem is covered quite well under graph theory.  In your case, simply pick a starting node and accumulate the closure.  If there are any nodes remaining outside that set, your graph isn't connected.  The remainder of your questions need to be (1) in separate postings; (2) defined well enough to allow clean answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets start with axis aligned cylinder. For such I see it like this:

1. **definition**

   let `XY` plane be the base and cylinder starts at `(0,0,0)` and grows into +Z direction up to distance `l` and have radius `r`. Also let me define `l0,l1` be the min and max distance between nodes.
2. **create main path**

   simply put a chain of connected nodes comming from start of cylinder ot its end. These will be used later to grow the clusters. This also ensures that path from start to end exist. So just add some randomized increments to `z` in range `<l0,~l1>` and use x,y as a randomized point inside some smaller circle than `r` to stay on path (I use 10% of `r`).
3. **grow clusters**

   simply take randomly any already placed point add a random displacement to it of size `<l0,l1>` and if still inside cylinder and not too close to any other point add it to your data and link it to the picked point. This can be speed up if you use points sorted by `z` so you can get rid of the `O(n)` search and use `O(log(n))` instead.

After this you just convert the axis aligned data into the final position and orientation you want. For example if you define your cylinder as 2 endpoints and radius then you can compute `l` as their distance, `l0,l1` as its fraction. Also you can compute 3 perpendicular basis vectors from it using simple vector math (2 representing `XY` plane and one representing cylinder axis `Z`) lets call them `u,v,w`. From that its just matter of vector math to convert... You can also construct 4x4 transform matrix from those and use that.

**Here small C++ example for this:**

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
const int N=200;    // points to generate
double pnt[N][3];   // random point
int    lnk[N];      // -1 or pnt[i] is linked to pnt[lnk[i]]
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void vector_mul(double *c,double *a,double *b) // c[3] = cross(a[3],b[3])
    {
    double   q[3];
    q[0]=(a[1]*b[2])-(a[2]*b[1]);
    q[1]=(a[2]*b[0])-(a[0]*b[2]);
    q[2]=(a[0]*b[1])-(a[1]*b[0]);
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++) c[i]=q[i];
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void generate(double *p0,double *p1,double r)
    {
    int i,j,k,ok;
    double u[3],v[3],w[3];      // basis vectors
    double a,dx,dy,dz,x,y,z,z0;
    double l;           // cylinder size |p1-p0|
    double l0=0.03;     // min distance between major nodes <0,1>
    double l1=0.06;     // max distance between major nodes <0,1>
    double ll0=l0*l0,ll1=l1*l1,rr=r*r;
    Randomize();
    // basis vectors from endpoints
    for (l=0.0,i=0;i<3;i++){ w[i]=p1[i]-p0[i]; l+=w[i]*w[i]; }  // w = (p1-p0)
    l=sqrt(l); l0*=l; l1*=l;                                    // l=|w| , convert l0,l1 to units
    for (i=0;i<3;i++) w[i]/=l;                                  // w/=|w|
    if (fabs(w[0])<0.75){ u[0]=1.0; u[1]=0.0; u[2]=0.0; }       // u=(1,0,0) or (0,1,0) so it is not paralel to w
     else               { u[0]=0.0; u[1]=1.0; u[2]=0.0; }
    vector_mul(v,u,w);                                          // v = cross(u,w)
    // [axis aligne d cylindric data]
    // random major path
    for (z0=0,i=0;i<N;)
        {
        x=2.0*r*Random()-r; x*=0.1; // use only 10% of x,y deviation to not sray too much
        y=2.0*r*Random()-r; y*=0.1;
        z=z0+l0+(0.75*(l1-l0)*Random()); if (z>l) break;
        // inside cylinder ?
        if ((z<0)||(z>l)) continue;
        if ((x*x)+(y*y)>rr) continue;
        // no point closer than l0 ?
        for (ok=1,j=0;j<i;j++)
            {
            dx=pnt[j][0]-x;
            dy=pnt[j][1]-y;
            dz=pnt[j][2]-z;
            if ((dx*dx)+(dy*dy)+(dz*dz)<ll0){ ok=0; break; }
            }
        if (!ok) continue;
        // add if valid point
        pnt[i][0]=x;
        pnt[i][1]=y;
        pnt[i][2]=z; lnk[i]=i-1; i++; z0=z;
        }
    // grow clusters
    for (;i<N;)
        {
        // random 3D displacement <l0,l1>
        for (;;)
            {
            dx=Random()-0.5;
            dy=Random()-0.5;
            dz=Random()-0.5;
            a=(dx*dx)+(dy*dy)+(dz*dz);
            if (a>1e-3) break;
            }
        a=(l0+((l1-l0)*Random()))/sqrt(a); dx*=a; dy*=a; dz*=a;
        // convert to position
        for (k=0;k<10;k++)
            {
            // add it to random point already placed
            j=Random(i); lnk[i]=j; ok=1;
            x=pnt[j][0]+dx;
            y=pnt[j][1]+dy;
            z=pnt[j][2]+dz;
            // inside cylinder ?
            if ((z<0)||(z>l)){ ok=0; break; }
            if ((x*x)+(y*y)>rr){ ok=0; break; }
            // no point closer than l0 ?
            for (j=0;j<i;j++)
                {
                dx=pnt[j][0]-x;
                dy=pnt[j][1]-y;
                dz=pnt[j][2]-z;
                if ((dx*dx)+(dy*dy)+(dz*dz)<ll0){ ok=0; break; }
                }
            if (ok) break;  // valid point
            }
        if (!ok) continue;
        // add if valid point
        pnt[i][0]=x;
        pnt[i][1]=y;
        pnt[i][2]=z; i++;
        }
    // [convert to final position and orientation]
    for (i=0;i<N;i++)
        {
        x=pnt[i][0];
        y=pnt[i][1];
        z=pnt[i][2];
        for (j=0;j<3;j++) pnt[i][j]=p0[j]+(x*u[j])+(y*v[j])+(z*w[j]);
        }
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

and usage:

```cpp
double p0[3]={-1.7,-0.5,-0.2};
double p1[3]={+1.7,+0.5,+0.4};
generate(p0,p1,0.5);
```

preview:

[image: preview]

**beware if you set too big `N` the second main loop can loop forever.** So you might want to add some ending condition like if continue was hit more than `2*i` times without `i` change stop. That is because `l0` constraint limits the max density of points and if `N` is bigger than that you can not add more points ...

Now if you want random radius spheres instead of the points than just add some random radius but do not forget to adjust the inside cylinder and closest distance tests by the radius ...

Comment: Thank you so much! I think your code absolutely does what I'm looking for, but I think I will need some time to reread and process in my mind what you wrote:)